# Extracting date only from the Date Field in Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a field of order date in my Order data Extension. In my email, I just have to use the date and not time. My take on this is:

```
%%[
VAR @OrderD
SET @OrderD = %%Order_Date%%
]%%
<p>
%%=Datepart(@OrderD,"D")=%% / %%=Datepart(@OrderD,"M")=%% / %%=Datepart(@OrderD,"Y")=%%
</p>
```

This is giving validation error. Please suggest what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using the [AttributeValue()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#attributevalue) and [format()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#format) functions:

```
%%[

VAR @OrderD
SET @OrderD = AttributeValue("Order_Date")

]%%

%%=format(@orderD,"dd/MM/yyyy")=%%
```